# How to add custom textbox field on shopify product page

Tags: shopify, custom-fields, shopify-template

I need to **add custom textbox** field on shopify product pages.

My requirement is to add textbox field on product page and when customer add product in cart than that textbox field value also display on cart page and also on checkout page.

I also need to reflect that textbox field value on admin custom order page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

For adding custom textbox field on shopify product page please follow below step :

1. Login to your shopify admin and ope product detail page template code
2. Copy and paste the code below into your product detail page template file between the  and  tags. The form textbox field will appear wherever you place the code.

```html
<p class="line-item-property__field">   <label for="custom-field">Your custom field</label>   <input id="custom-field" type="text" name="properties[Your custom field]"> </p>
```

3. Save file.

After adding above code custom textbox field will be appear on your product detail page.

You can also use this link as reference for adding different type of custom field on product detail page : [Shopify line item properties](https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/line-item-property)

Answer (score -2):

a much more easier way is to use the following Shopify App:
https://apps.shopify.com/Textfield

It let‘s you create easy and fast different kind of text fields.